# standard error of variance components of lmer model when REML=TRUE

Tags: r, lme4

I want to calculate the standard error of restricted maximum likelihood estimates of variance  components of `lmer` model in R .

It will be very helpful if it is shown for the following example :

```
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days||Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Comment: Probably best to link to previous question.  Can you say what you're going to use the standard errors for?

Comment: @BenBolker in two level model , I am trying to show that the standard errors of the second-level variances are estimated too small when the number of groups is substantially lower than 100 .

Comment: how about using likelihood profile confidence intervals and showing that the coverage is smaller than nominal?

Comment: @BenBolker  `confint` produces `NA` in some replicates and if I omit this  , coverage probability becomes higher than the nominal even when there is only 10 groups .

Comment: `lmer`  produces warning when I have small sample size ,
 but doesn't produce any warning if I have a large sample size . 
And when I calculate the likelihood profile confidence interval by `confint`, it produce some `NA` in  many replications . and when I omit the missing value , the coverage probability becomes higher than the nominal .